# Remoção de arquivos em c

Tags: c

Estou fazendo um trabalho e cheguei numa parte de remover arquivo que o usuario deseja, porem ele lê e não remove. para remover eu deveria usar extensão (.txt)? se sim, como?

```
void removeCliente() {
    char codigo [50]; int excl;
    int *p;
    char * file_name;
    //FILE* verifica;
    printf("entre com o código do cliente que deseja excluir:");
    scanf("%s",&codigo);
    file_name=codigo;

      FILE *fo = fopen(file_name,"r");
    if (fo == NULL){
        printf("Ocorreu um erro!");
        //return 0;
    }

    else{
            fclose(file_name);
    fflush(stdin);
       remove(file_name);
    printf("usuario %d removido com sucesso");
    //sleep(10);
    }
    menugerente();
}
```

Comment: O nome do arquivo deve ser exatamente o mesmo que o que existe. Se possui extensão, deverá colocá-la. E se for em outro diretório, deverá ter o caminho completo.

Comment: é no mesmo diretorio. mas como vou colocar a extensão do arquivo? se o nome de entrada não possui

Comment: Minha resposta resolveu seu problema? Caso sim, marque-a como respondido. Caso não tenha sido, diga-nos o que ainda está em dúvida. Caso não saiba como marcar como resposta, dê uma olhada em https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 0):

Como havia comentado, parece que sua entrada não possui a extensão do arquivo e seu arquivo possui.

Você pode usar um [sprintf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/sprintf/) para gerar o novo nome do arquivo.

Então, você pode fazer da seguinte forma:

```
void removeCliente() {
    char codigo[50];
    char file_name[32];

    printf("Entre com o código do cliente que deseja excluir:");

    scanf("%s", &codigo);

    // Setamos a variável file_name como sendo o texto de codigo mais a adição do texto "txt"
    sprintf(file_name, "%s.txt", codigo);

    FILE *fo = fopen(file_name, "r");
    if (fo == NULL) 
        printf("Ocorreu um erro! O usuario não existe");
    else 
    {
        fclose(fo);
        fflush(stdin);
        remove(file_name);
        // Você havia colocado um %d sendo que era uma string, então, alterei para %s
        printf("usuario %s removido com sucesso", codigo);
    }

    menugerente();
}
```

Também saliento que caso esteja em outra pasta, você deveria colocar o caminho completo para remover corretamente.

Então, seu `sprintf` poderia ter um argumento a mais sendo o caminho padrão, definido em algum lugar do seu projeto.

Exemplo:

`sprintf(file_name, "%s\\%s.txt", caminho_do_arquivo, codigo);`

Comment: entendi, muito obrigada